# V-data-table showing total number of pages

Tags: datatable, pagination, vuetify.js

Good morning,
I am creating the table with pagination in my project using v-data-table.
All is working correctly, I am just trying to add total number of pages to the pagination.
What I have now:

```
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="filteredList"
            :items-per-page="7"
            no-data-text="No results"
            :footer-props="{
              itemsPerPageText: 'Items per page:',
              itemsPerPageOptions: itemsPerPages,
              showCurrentPage: true
            }"
          >
          </v-data-table>
```

The thing is, showCurrentPage displays only the number of current page (between prev/next page buttons). Is it possible to change it to something like:
`Page 1 of 3`?

[pagination screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaKuB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a [slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots) for `v-data-table` that will replace the page text. Personally have not used a slot for this scenario and this example is off the top of my head but it should be along the lines of:

```html
<v-data-table>
  <template v-slot:footer.page-text="{ pageStart, pageStop, itemsLength }">
    {{ pageStart }} of {{ itemsLength }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

If the slot does not work as intended, then you have the option to create a custom slot for the whole footer to add the page count. Unfortunately this will replace the default footer so you will have to recreate the other elements in the footer like items per page dropdown and page navigation.

```html
<v-data-table>
  <template v-slot:footer="{ props }">
    // Every other footer element
    {{ props.pagination.page }} of {{ props.pagination.pageCount }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, pageText is the part where all items are counted (the one before previous page button), so this is not what I am looking for as I would like this part as well. I will try with a custom slot than, thanks!